# How to compare two strings which having (á,í,ä) like characters in c#?

Tags: c#

I need to compare two strings in a word document I work it out for alphabetic and numeric values but it is not able to compare a string which contains some special characters like Máceres-Cartínez(á,í,ä) my code did not consider this occurrence as a string.
        StreamWriter(fsf);

```
    swt.WriteLine("Startred on :" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss") + "\n");

    swf.WriteLine("Startred on :" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss") + "\n");


    foreach (string strPara in strParaValue)

      {
          string[] strAuthorsPart = strPara.Split('.');

          string[] strAuthorslist = strAuthorsPart[0].Split(',');

          string[] strAuthor = strAuthorslist[0].Split(' ');

          if (strSplitValue[0].Contains(strAuthor[0].Trim()))

         {

             swt.WriteLine(strAuthor[0] + "\t");

         }

              else

         {

             swf.WriteLine(strAuthor[0] + "\t");

         }

              swt.WriteLine("\r\n");

              swf.Flush();

          }
```

Please let me suggest on this regards.

DeeGo

Comment: -1. Please review your code sample and remove commented out stuff unrelated to the question and mark a place that is causeing you problems.

Comment: This is my function Here two string compare with other and produce the output

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to ignore [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritics) when comparing two strings, i.e. `"Maceres"` should match   `"Máceres"`.

If that is correct, the simplest solution is to *remove* diacritics from both strings and *then* compare them. The following question contains suggestions on how to do that:

- [How do I remove diacritics (accents) from a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net)